# Difference between axios({method: "post"}) and axios.post()

Tags: javascript, api, shopify, graphql, axios

I'm using Shopify Storefront API and Axios to develop locally a e-shop.

Shopify give me a response when I use `axios()`, but it returns `403 Forbidden` when I do the same thing with `axios.post()`.

What's the difference between those two?

```js
axios.post(
    SHOPIFY_DOMAIN,
    {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
        "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": SHOPIFY_TOKEN
    },
    data: `{ shop }`
})
```

```js
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: SHOPIFY_DOMAIN,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
    "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": SHOPIFY_TOKEN
  },
  data: `{ shop }`
})
```

Comment: it just a short hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of `axios.post` is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`. The correct way of using is:

```
axios.post(
    SHOPIFY_DOMAIN,
    `{ shop }`,
    {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
            "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": SHOPIFY_TOKEN
        }
    }
);
```

See also: [axios API](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api)

Comment: Your answer is way clearer than that documentation bit. Thanks mate.